# Display 12 hour time format with AM/PM in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, datetime-format

I want to add AM/PM in 12hour time using ALTER SESSION.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss ';
```

Here's sample output dates

| Date Modified | Closed Date | Date Assigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/17/2018 9:18:18 AM | 5/17/2018 9:18:18 AM | 5/16/2018 3:54:39 PM |

Comment: You have not yet mentioned the data type of these columns.  We could assume the are correctly defined as DATE, but we could assume incorrectly.  If they are NOT defined as DATE (which would be a design failure) then any supplied answers will be dependent on implied to_char/to_date conversions which could very will lead to unintended results.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `AM` or `PM` format model and change `YY` to `YYYY` (you can also use `HH12` to be explicit that you want a 12-hour clock):

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM';
```

If you do not want leading zeroes in then add the `FM` format model:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='FMMM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM';
```

Comment: Tried it already, but it returns 'PM' in all of the date-hour column.

Comment: @KayeAndreaFernandez Then check your data and make sure your data is actually AM and not PM. Use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` to get the values in the 24 hour clock and make sure the hour is `09` and not `21`. If your data is actually 9pm then there is nothing that we can do with the format model to fix bad data.

Comment: 24HH
Opened  5/9/2018  3:32:33
Date Mod 5/17/2018 13:18:18
Closed  5/17/2018 13:18:18
Date Ass 5/16/2018 15:54:39

12HH
Opened  5/9/2018  7:32:33 PM
Date Mod 5/17/2018 1:18:18 PM
Closed  5/17/2018 1:18:18 PM
Date Ass 5/16/2018 3:54:39 PM

Comment: @KayeAndreaFernandez Your "Opened" value makes no sense as you have `03` in 24-hour clock and `7 pm` in 12-hour clock; those are not even the same numeric values. What do you get if you use `DUMP(opened)` in a `SELECT` statement for that row? All the other values are identical and the use of PM is correct for them.